# how to get the user's ip address on web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem to get the user's ip address into web server.
I am using this code..

```
//To get the local IP address 
            string sHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipE = Dns.GetHostByName(sHostName);
            IPAddress[] IpA = ipE.AddressList;
            for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IpA[i].ToString());
                string IPAddress= IpA[i].ToString();//ip;// IPAddress;// strIPAddress;
            }
```

due to this I am getting user IP address into local host accurate but when I upload my website into web server than it's having all user's ip address same as server IP address... please guys help me.

Answer (score 4):

That code will get you the IP address of the server.

You can access the user's IP address with this property: `Request.UserHostAddress`

Comment: `string IPAddress=Request.UserHostAddress;`

You can use that from the same place you currently have the block of code in your example. If that doesn't work, please let us know the location of that current code you're using.

Comment: Exactly thats iP Address of server. Have a look at this article for client ip  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/getting-client-ip-address-or-local-ip-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Get users IP address

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
or
Request.UserHostAddress
```

To get the IP address of the machine and not the proxy use the following code

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

This link help you more..

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/260872/How-to-get-client-IP-in-asp-net-Csharp

Comment: In Page_Load or any Event function when you can get Request.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have used only work in case of windows application (Client server architecture)
But to get the users ip address in web application you need to use

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how hard you try you can only get server IP using server side code in Asp.Net.However the method told in this article will let you access client ip using javascript.refer this
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/getting-client-ip-address-or-local-ip-address-in-javascript